# An extension of the real semiring with multiple degrees of infinity

Tags: power-series, automata-theory, semirings

Is it possible to define an extension of the probability semiring $(\mathbb{R}^+, +, \times, 0, 1)$ such that

- Closure $a^* = 1 + a + a^2 + \ldots$ is defined for every element of the semiring, not just for those less than $1$;
- The semiring is divisible and cancellable.
- There exists a total order on the elements of the semiring, such that

  - $a^* > b^*$ for any $a > b$
  - Higher-order infinities are greater than the lower-order ones: $(a^*)^* > b^*$ for any $a$ and $b$ (except where the corresponding geometric series converges to a finite value).
  - A sum or a product of a finite number of infinities is less than the next level of infinity: $a^*b^*c^* < (d^*)^*$ (again, assuming that all the involved geometric series diverge).
  - **[optional]** $0 < \frac{1^*}{1^* + 2^*} < \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ (so, division by a higher-order infinity results in an "infinitesimal" value). Analogously, $1 < \frac{2^*}{1^* + 2^*} < 1+\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.
- The semiring can be efficiently implemented on a computer, meaning that the representation of the semiring elements is finite and, preferrably, short (assuming the floating point approximation being used), and the operations can be implemented with a reasonably low space and time complexity.

Are any such extensions known in literature? If not, is there a fundamental reason why such a semiring cannot be consistently defined?

To provide some background, I'm wondering whether it's possible to define a semiring such that every weighted automaton over that semiring will have well-defined values and a normalizer despite the presence of "diverging" loops.

Comment: What do you mean by `divisible semiring'? Does it mean that you have an operation of division inverse to multiplication? If so (and if you have a multiplicative unity) then your conditions are contradictory, because $(1^*+2^*)^{-1}$ should be zero and non-zero simultaneously (notice that $0a=a0=0$ by the definition of a semiting - or do you omit this?).

Comment: Yes, I mean that for every element $a$ there exists element $a^{-1}$ such that $aa^{-1}=a^{-1}a=1$. You made a fair point. I probably have to tweak conditions to introduce not only infinite, but also infinitesimal values.

Comment: I've modified my question, removing the inconsistent condition.

Comment: I still don't quite get the "dominance" property of divisibility; assuming $(a/b)*b$ should be $a$, your second example gives $2^*=1^*+2^*$, so that either $1^*=0$, or your semiring is not cancellable - are you ok with the latter?

Comment: You're right, it's hardly a desirable property. I should update the conditions on the desired semiring, requiring, say, for $\frac{1^*}{1^* + 2^*}$ to be an "infinitely small" value greater than zero.

Comment: I've replaced the original requirement based on division by the strict ordering requirement.

Comment: Well, do you need the closure to be defined for all elements but not for those from $\mathbb R^+$? If no, how can one interprete $(A^*)^*$? Otherwise, how to interprete the condition $(A^*)^*>b^*$ (what would you do if $a^*=b$?)?

Comment: One more remark. If you wish the sum of infinite number of elements to satisfy some `natural' properties, several of them imply that $1^*=1+1+1+\dots=1+1^*$; so the semiring cannot be cancellable in this case.

Comment: Many of your axioms are satisfied if you just consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the operation $a^*=1/(1-a)$.  Of course $1^*$ is undefined, but $1^*$ is problematic anyway, as Ilya points out.  It would be helpful if you could clarify why this extension is unsuitable for your applications.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is not what you want, because I do not realize which restrictions you put on ``infinite sums''. They are not defined in a usual semiring, so right now I assume that you merely wish all the elements $a^*$ to exist.

In order to fulfill the third condition you simply need that $2^*+1^*=2^*$. Here is one of the ways to perform this.

Let $S=\{0\}\cup (\mathbb R_{>0}\times \mathbb R)$. Zero is isolated, so the operations with it are trivial. For all other elements, we put $(a,b)\cdot (c,d)=(ac,b+d)$ and
$$
  (a,b)+(c,d)=\begin{cases}
    (a,b), & b>d;\\
    (c,d), & b<d;\\
    (a+c,b), &b=d.
  \end{cases}
$$
This is a semifield, $(1,0)$ is multiplicative identity, and $\{0\}\cup (\mathbb R_{>0}\times\{0\})$ is a subsemifield isomorphic to the probability semiring. Now we may define $a^*$ as $(1,a)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it clearly shows that I have to think more about the requirements I would like to impose on the inifite sums. In the semiring semiring you propose, for instance, $\frac{1^*}{2^*} = 0.5$, which I intuitively fill to be wrong.

Comment: No, $\frac{1^*}{2^*}$ is not $0.5$; it is a completely different element, namely $(1,-1)$.

Comment: Sorry, that's true, looks like I've accidentaly swapped $a$ and $b$ when computing this. How would you then define the closure of an infinite sum in this semiring, i.e. what is $(1, 1)^*$?

Comment: Well, honestly speaking, I do not know. If you need to have only these sums --- then why not to set it by the definition? Otherwise, perhaps, you wish a larger class of infinite sums to be computable; in this case it would be better to specify this class...

Comment: In any case, it seems that after the set up was completely changed, it does not matter anymore.

Comment: It is not exactly the same framework, but maybe you will be interested in this: http://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/lics/2013/5020/00/5020a123-abs.html
It is also related with weighted automata and different orders of "infinity"